# Why aren't my variables printing? PHP

Tags: php

Could anyone tell me why my character stats will not print? I'm not getting any error or syntax messages..

This is my first php project ever. I can't figure out what I'm missing!

```
<?  
    class character{
        public $healthpoints = 100;
        public $isdead = false;
        public $class = "Mage";
        public $level = 10;
    }


    function checkdeath() {
    if($healthpoints >= 0){
        $isdead = true;
        }   
    }

    new character();

    function CharStats() {
        echo $healthpoints;
        echo $isdead;
        echo $class;
        echo $level;
    }

    CharStats;


    ?>
```

Comment: This a variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Your class variables are not in scope of your function. Easy solution is to add your function to your class as a class method

Comment: It starts with reading the error messages: https://3v4l.org/he30R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Thinking, **ALL**

```
class Character{
    public $healthpoints = 100;
    public $isdead = false;
    public $class = "Mage";
    public $level = 10;

    function checkdeath() {
       if($this->healthpoints >= 0){
        $this->isdead = true;
      }   
    }

    function CharStats() {
        echo $this->healthpoints;
        echo $this->$isdead;
        echo $this->$class;
        echo $this->$level;
    }

}

$character = new Character();
$character->ChatStats();
```

Read again about classes/objects/etc. - [Classes and Objects in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: A class method should not echo anything. Perhaps out of scope, but returning a sttring, then proxied via __toString() and then echo'ing the object variable might be (more) appropriate..

Comment: Excellent, thanks guys I got it working exactly as I wanted. I changed my $isdead to a string that is merely now yes or no.